# a way not to show izpack

Tags: izpack

I have successfully compiled and created a Java installer. However, I don't want those izpack things on the installation windows. Is there a way inside install.xmml to get rid of those things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can easily do that.

What type of things you don't want to show?
I am quoting an example here that will help you to add your heading.

> Adding headline to you custom panel To
>   add heading to your custom panel add
>   following line to you lanuage pack xml
>   file. Go to
>   IzPack\bin\langpacks\installer open
>   your language pack xml file e.g
>   eng.xml. Add this line
>        ere TestPanel is
>   the name of your panel and text in
>   txt="Test Heading" is the heading to
>   be shown in TestPanel.